# Representing an entire day or week or month as a number like timestamp

Tags: math

How can a day or week or month, essentially a range of time be represented by a single number?

The next interval would represent a number 1 more than the number for the previous interval, just how the next second is 1 more than the previous second, in timestamp representation.

Given a bunch of such numbers, the larger number simply means its representing a time interval afterwards in time, when compared to a number smaller than it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized if I stick to UTC and represent the day as YYYYMMDD, this becomes a number that I am looking for.

```
20180420 // 20 april 2018
20180421 // 21 april 2018
20180510 // 10 may 2018
20190101 // 1 jan 2019
```

This works for representing a day perfectly, I think.

For week, maybe do `ceil()` of days of current month divided by 7 for representing week as a number `W` and then using the format: `YYYYMMW`.

```
2018043 // 3rd week of april 2018
2018045 // 5th week of april 2018, though may not be the 5th week semantically but representation model works, greater than 4th week of april 2018 and smaller number than 1st week of may 2018
```

For month, simply `YYYYMM` works.

I feel so smart right now!